# Parse XML string on BlackBerry

Tags: java, blackberry

I am trying to parse XML with the following code, but StringReader is not available in the BlackBerry JDE.  What is the right way to do this?

```
            DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
            InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xmlRecords));
            Document doc = db.parse(is);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String xmlString = "<xml> </xml>" // your xml string    

ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlString.getBytes("UTF-8"));

Document doc = builder.parse(bis);
```

Try this out

Answer (score 2):

If you want to build a DOM from data coming from a server, you're much better off parsing the InputStream directly with a DocumentBuilder rather than reading the data into a String and trying to work with that. One way is:

```
Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse(input);
```